# ¿Por qué me sale el error "el objeto no es una matriz" en R?

Tags: r, regresión-lineal

Estoy intentando realizar un modelo lineal con un dataframe. Al ejecutar la sentencia me sale el siguiente error:

```
mod1<-lm(MCIGARRILLOS$Logcigarillos~MCIGARRILLOS$Logprecio~MCIGARRILLOS$LogSalario)
```

Error in model.frame.default(formula = MCIGARRILLOS$Logcigarillos ~ MCIGARRILLOS$Logprecio ~  :
objeto no es una matriz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

la formula para hacer un modelo lineal es de este tipo :

```
lm(dependiente~independiente1+independiente2, n... data=datos)
```

Revisa si tu variable dependiente la quieres modelar en función de tus otras variables.
Con tu ejemplo, `MCIGARRILLOS$Logcigarillos` seria tu variable dependiente y las otras 2 serian tus independientes. Quedaría así.

```
mod1<-lm(MCIGARRILLOS$Logcigarillos~ MCIGARRILLOS$Logprecio + MCIGARRILLOS$LogSalario)
```

Comment: Lo pruebo, pensaba que era un tema del formato, que era un dataframe en lugar de una matriz. Pero como bien indicas, no había puesto el signo +. Lo vuelvo a probar.

Comment: Y para editar el modelo: summary(mod1)

Comment: Recuerda poner data = "tus datos" al final, como esta en el ejemplo que te he puesto. Te ha funcionado?

Comment: Excelente. Pon como resuelta la pregunta dándole click a mi respuesta inicial. Así cualquier otra persona que tenga el mismo problema lo puede resolver también. Un saludo

Comment: @santonla aunque hayas sido quien redactó la pregunta, _debe ser el autor de la respuesta quien edite el código_. Podés dejar el trozo de código a reemplazar como comentario como para que lo pueda editar, y una vez editado, podés borrar de nuevo el comentario.

Comment: OK. no he cambiado el código. Simplemente he añadido los datos solicitados.